# What things can a Muslim not research/ask about?

Tags: halal-haram, allah

I have came across few things (like about Allah/God existence, location, why, how, and many things about it) and I am always told that its not good thing to talk about it or its forbidden. Isn't there any reason why?

Comment: can you give prooflinks about that? i know there is an ayat where it is said to not ask about something.

Answer (score 3):

One can ask any question about anything in Islam. But what is discouraged is thinking about essence of God. And the reason mentioned is that the essence of God is beyond understanding of human and can lead to perplexity.

> Allah knows what is [presently] before them and what will be after
>   them, **but they do not encompass it in knowledge**.
>   http://tanzil.net/#20:110

In this verse is said that human cannot encompass the knowing God.

It is like trying to each a mountain by teeth. It is basically impossible and the only result is losing teeth. Or it is like one person trying to drink all waters of an ocean.

We can understand only creations of God and [attributes of God](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_God_in_Islam) and cannot understand what is essence of God itself.

Different hadith from Ahl al Bayt discourage thinking to essence of God and instead recommend thinking about attributes and creations of God.

In fact human does not have the ability to understand essence of God.

Please note this does not mean stopping knowing God. Knowing God is the best valuable and enjoyable knowledge and prayer human can have ever. The attributes and creations of God are unlimited sources of knowing God. But the discourage is only about thinking about what is essence of God.

Comment: If God gave me the brain to think and explore. Why he wouldn't want me to think about something? What if one keep finding and understand the essence of God and still have belief on Him ?  and can you please provide the reference from Quran which exactly mention that "Seeking for God's Essence is a sin" ?

Comment: Surah Al-Isra verse 36.